# Как в Google Sheets создать выпадающий список, берущий данный с другого листа?

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

Вопрос относительно работы в `Google Sheets`:
Я хочу создать в таблице выпадающий список, который будет брать данные из нескольких колонок на другом листе и подставлять их на текущий лист. На скриншоте более подробно. Возможно ли такое реализовать, и если да - то как?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Список создается с помощью "проверки данных". Допустим, с помощью выпадающего меню по правой кнопке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там Вы указываете нужный диапазон с данными:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Во второй ячейке используете формулу [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=ru)

```
=VLOOKUP(A1;'Лист7'!$A$1:$B$3;2;0)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает!

Comment: Как к выпадающему списку добавить данные с другого листа? То есть к выпадающем значениям Арт1, Артём и тд, я хочу добавить значения Box, Box2 и тд с другого списка. Это возможно?

Answer (score 0):

Может кому-то еще поможет.
На видео полностью описан процесс как использовать связку "Проверка данных" (выпадающий список) с ВПР (при выборе пункта меню которого будут отбражаться данные с другого листа) в Google Таблицах, т.е. это видео-ответ на данный вопрос:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLGYaBY9ZGc

Если коротко то, например:
Я хочу чтобы при выборе артикла подтягивалась цена
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значит на другом листе с помощью проверки данных я делаю выпадающий список из артиклов
А рядом вставляю формулу ВПР
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)